# How do I stop view controllers from being clear color?

Tags: objective-c

I have created a screen tutorial for my app.
I've done this by creating a `PageViewController` to manage 4 `viewControllers`.
In the `PageViewController` I have implemented the following code

`self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;`
I have also set the alpha on the pageViewController view to .45

This makes the `PageViewController` transparent which is exactly what I want.
However, it is also making everything inside the 4 `viewControllers` that are being managed by the PageViewController transparent i.e. buttons, labels, etc.

How can I stop all of those object from being transparent?

Comment: View controllers are not interface objects. They have no color. Views have color.

Comment: I stand corrected. Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views always work like this. If you wanted to make a view semi-transparent, it would usually be pretty vexing if that didn't also affect all of its subviews. The times when you want your alpha setting to also affect the subviews likely far outnumber the times when you don't.

What you can do instead of making the *view* transparent is to make its *background color* transparent. That is, instead of:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
self.view.alpha = 0.45;
```

you can do:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:.45];
```

That way, your subviews are not affected, because while the alpha of your main view's background color is 0.45, the alpha of the view itself is still 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

To change the background color of a view, use the following on the view:

```
[viewController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor COLOR]];
```

where COLOR is the color you would like (i.e. whiteColor)

Comment: Choppin, I have edited my question. I just realized that I did not ask what I was thinking. The background color of the view I can modify. The problem is the Alpha of the objects in the view. They are all transparent like if I had set an alpha.